# Confused about Debian error message from su

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

On Raspbian, the Debian distro aimed at RPi, I end up getting the following error:

```
$ sudo su -l root -c /bin/bash
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

... however, if I change this to `sudo su -`, everything works fine. Any ideas what's wrong in the above command line? The main issue here is that the terminal is borked after this command ...

I found [this bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=659878) but it looks like there is no clonclusion.

---

### System info

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 (wheezy)
Release:        7.0
Codename:       wheezy
$ dpkg -l |grep sudo
ii  libgksu2-0                            2.0.13~pre1-6                        armhf        library providing su and sudo functionality
ii  sudo                                  1.8.5p2-1                            armhf        Provide limited super user privileges to specific users
```

---

### NOTE

The reason I am using `-c /bin/bash` is that it actually looks more like `-c /bin/bash --rcfile /path/to/rcfile` ... and therefore is different from a mere `sudo -i` or `sudo su -` and so on ...

The reason I gave the command line as I did above in my question was that it is the minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: What is your aim in doing `sudo su -l root -c /bin/bash`? That is an extremely convoluted way of getting a root shell...

Comment: Looks like this is a legit regression from a security fix that wheezy will release with.

Comment: What's all this `-l root -c /bin/bash` stuff? Why not just do this `sudo su -`?  If the problem is that root's default shell is not bash, then why not change root's default shell to bash?

Comment: There are parameters such as `--rcfile` past the `/bin/bash`. But they aren't relevant to reproduce the issue. What I produced here is a minimal working example to reproduce the bug. Without the `-c` part and everything following, this error doesn't occur. This is *why* this "convoluted" way ...

Comment: @jordanm You were right. I'm getting this error just by doing `su user -` and I couldn't find a way around it. To make things worse, a `^C` in the console will terminate it! If I open another bash from it and hit `^C`, the console will randomly alternate between the root and the user console, so typing a command will send some letters to one console an other letters to the other. WTF? I can't find any work-arounds for this problem. (edit: Debian Wheezy, LXTerminal, user doing the `su` is root)

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of digging, it seems that **this is expected behavior for now**, because it's a security fix. On the other hand, I've discovered that it also adds a small security risk, but I'll have to do some more digging to make sure I'm not mistaking before reporting it to the Debian guys.

Here is the bug they fixed: [login: tty hijacking possible in "su" via TIOCSTI ioctl](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=628843)

My understanding is that the `su` command used to leave `/dev/tty` open for the called process and so the process, even with lowered privileges could inject code in the terminal that would be executed after the `su` command ended. They patched it (I would say monkey-patched it) by closing the tty, which is why the newly started bash is complaining.