# How can I sudo su and change directory just after?

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, su

I would like to create an alias that does something like this:

```
alias userYYY='sudo su userYYY; cd /a/path/that/only/userYYY/has/access'
```

So then from my command line, I am logged in with a sudo user, and I would like to type the alias `userYYY` so that my shell is now logged with `userYYY` and `pwd` is `/a/path/that/only/userYYY/has/access`.

How can I do that?  This `userYYY` is for running some processes, and there must be anything in its home. Hence, I tried changing its $HOME using:

```
sudo usermod -m -d /a/path/that/only/userYYY/has/access userYYY
```

And then from my shell with my sudoer file I did `sudo su userYYY`. But that didn't work. The only that worked was `sudo su -l userYYYY` but that opened a new bash inside my original shell (`-bash-4.1$ ....`).

In summary, what I want is to simply avoid having to write 2 lines in my shell:

```
sudo su userYYY
cd /a/path/that/only/userYYY/has/access
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
alias userYYY='sudo su userYYY -c "cd /a/path/that/only/userYYY/has/access; /bin/bash"'
```

Comment: seems to work fine, but not sure how to remove this error, or if its an issue.  using ubuntu 14.04LTS, noticed there was an issue with on debian...
`bash: cannot set terminal process group (13964): Inappropriate ioctl for device\nbash: no job control in this shell`

Comment: actually, after using it for a while, i noticed that the terminal gets killed pretty frequently using this method (disconnect around 15-30 min, regularly, my terminal lasts around 6hrs before disconnect)

Comment: Just dug up this, this behaviour is due to a security fix:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65843/confused-about-debian-error-message-from-su

Comment: this has helped me edit my `.bashrc` file to `sudo` then `cd` where as having 2 separate lines just wasn't working.

Answer (score 7):

One option would be to edit `~/.bashrc` of the target user, and add `cd` there:

```
cd /a/path/that/only/userYYY/has/access
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is slightly different than the original question, but the idea is to run the command as a different user without typing in a password when policy prohibits `sudo su <user> -c`.

```
sudo -u userYYY -- sh -c "cd /a/path/that/only/userYYY/has/access; /bin/bash"
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you can't. The `sudo su` starts a new shell which must exit before it gets to the `cd` command.

Answer (score 0):

For me a combination of `sudo` and `screen` worked out:

```
sudo -iu vagrant screen -mS npm_install bash -c 'cd /vagrant && npm install'
```

This command first switches to the `vagrant` user. Then as `vagrant` changes the directory to `/vagrant` and executes `npm install`.